# Footer position changes everytime

Tags: html, css, angular, footer

I have been trying to create a reusable footer component and want it to place at the bottom irrespective of the content between header and footer but for some pages, it stays at bottom and some pages, it either comes on top or in between.

Can someone try to help me with this?

app.component.html

```
<custom-theme>
  <div class="">
    <div class="">
      <div class="">
        <menu></menu>
      </div>
      <div class="">
        <breadcrumb></breadcrumb>
        <div class="app-header">
          <img />
          <div class="header-icon">
            <img alt="Language" class="header-icon-image"/>
            <div class="header-icon-text"</div>
          </div>
          <div class="header-icon-container">
            <img class="header-icon"/>
            <div class="header-icon-text"</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="app-container">
          <router-outlet class="col-12"></router-outlet>
        </div>
        <div class="app-footer">
          <footer></footer>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</custom-theme>
```

app.component.css

```
.app-container {
  position: relative;
  left: 35px;
  width: 98%;
  top: 50px;
}
.app-header {
  background: #f4f4f4;
  /* left: 40px; */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
}

.app-footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 98%;
  clear: both;
}
```

Footer.component

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="dateinfo">
    <p>Date</p>
  </div>
  <div class="imprint">
    <p>imprint</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Footer.component.css

```
.container {
  padding: 10px;
}

.dateinfo{
  margin-left: 42px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.imprint {
  margin-right: 30px;
  float: right;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should wrap your whole component into a container with min-height: 100% and position: relative. keep your app.footer class as it is. For more info, read this [Article](https://matthewjamestaylor.com/bottom-footer)

Comment: can you please elaborate? I read and tried to do the same but still, it overlaps on some pages where content is displayed dynamically.